# @SpringBootApplication cannot be resolved to a type. I have tried everything but only this error remains

Tags: spring-boot

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;

/**
 * Spring boot main Application
 *
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't going to get much help if you don't provide some more details. If you want to get starter, go on https://start.spring.io and you'll be able to generate a basic project that works.

Comment: @shubham singla  Which build tool you are using? Maven or Gradle.
I guess you are not resolving dependencies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@SpringBootApplication cannot be resolved to a type In STS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668819/springbootapplication-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-in-sts)

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing it with gradle. Make sure you have `"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE"` at classpath and `apply plugin :'org.springframework.boot'` included in your bulid.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

add above dependency

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and manage to solve it by

deleting all maven local repo and update it back using maven -> update project

Answer (score 0):

When I set the sourceCompatibility to the correct version in build.gradle, it fixed my error.

Also, gradle version should be compatible to the Java version.

Answer (score -1):

This may be due to "spring-boot-starter-parent" version issue.

i have changed the version it resolved the errors.

Comment: He did not specify any version and I am pretty sure it is due to missing dependency, not wrong version.