# @SpringBootApplication cannot be resolved to a type In STS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am very new to STS. I searched for this error in stackoverflow. I didn't find correct matching answer.

I am able to see the class in MavenDependencies seciton in STS but not able to add the annotation in my java class.

[image]
Your help will be appriciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: You will need to import it.

Comment: Bro its there in classpath as you can see in the above pic.

Comment: Should i re import it? or what you wants me to do?

Comment: I got it. The problem is class is there but i am not able to import it.

Comment: ensure that it is in your build path

Comment: If your application is a maven project, then update your project once and do a clean build. That should refresh the dependencies.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Go to your maven repository directory
For windows on below path
`C:\Users\YourUser\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot`
Then delete `spring-boot-autoconfigure` folder.

Now go to eclipse `Right click on project -> Maven -> Update Project`.

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: I also deleted *spring-boot* folder and then worked. Thanks!

Comment: On linux is ~/.m2

Comment: I was working on IntelliJ Idea and I had to delete both '.idea' and this folder to make it work

Answer (score 5):

Run bellow commands from command line

```
mvn clean dependency:tree
mvn clean compile
```

select project and do a maven->update
This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Just change your spring boot version into 1.5.6 from 1.5.8.
trust me i have tried every other solution but only this solution worked for me.

Comment: that is in your pom.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the above solutions worked for me as my code was this

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>    
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

I was missing the `<dependencies>` tag which lead to this error.

Answer (score 0):

Add the import statement below your package declaration.

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

You only need to add that annotation to your entry point, not every class. It goes on the same class that holds the main method to start Spring...

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CourseAPIApp.class, args);
}
```

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: i tried this. Please check the question i have edited it

Comment: @Abdul The import statement looks correct to me. Did you add your Spring boot dependencies via maven? Try rebuilding the project.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your *org/springframework/boot* folder under *.m2/* file location and run **mvn clean install** command under project

Answer (score 0):

import the following:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I am not sure if we got there for the same reason. In my case, the Spring Initializr generated my project with this tag on pom.xml file:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

But 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT doesn't even exist yet for this artifact. I went to the maven repository page, and I got the most recent one (currently 2.7.0), reloaded the project and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

in Spring Tool Suite
gradle > refresh gradle project
should get it all working again

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. You can resolve it with building the project with the `"eclipse:eclipse"` goal.